# Multiple fragments or nested fragments

Tags: android, nested, fragment, swipe

I am writing an android app that will have a number of different screens that I would like to swipe between, each screen will be a full page except for action bar header. On each screen there is the ability to open up another screen which will also be multiple screens that I would like swipeable. What is the best way to handle this. Do I have one fragment manager that holds all the screens and handle the onPageScrollStateChanged to only allow swipes between the current accessable screens or would I be best off nesting the fragments. I hope the above makes sense.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want to use a [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) to to swipe between views (Fragment extends View)

You could either:

1. In a single activity use a  FragmentManager that switches between the parent and child Fragments, each with their own ViewPager and nested Fragments
2. Start a new activity to hold each ViewPager

Both are valid, if the Fragments need to communicate with each other or the Activity option one  might suit the project needs better.

Comment: I should have mentioned I was aware I would need to use a ViewPager. Do you have any code in reference to option 1 or could point me towards a tutorial. I have done some work with ViewPager and fragments I'm just not sure how to handle the switching between parent and child fragments. Thanks

Comment: @user3703417 Just use a FragmentTrasaction http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Transactions

Answer (score 0):

For the swiping between views you indeed need a [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html)

For the nested fragments I would use a wrapper. I struggled a lot with fragments and found that this is the best way. A wrapper is very simple. This is just a fragment that holds other fragments. In the `onCreate()` of this fragment you get the childFragmentManager and add the fragment you originionally wanted to add. If you want to go to a new fragment you simply get the childFragmentManager again and replace the current item. This way you have nested fragment. You can add this to the backstack in order to get back navigation, but you need to override `onBackPressed()` inside your activity and call the method `popBackStack()` from the fragmentManager in order to get the first fragment back.

If you have any questions, comment below.